# 10 GB file of "size-on-disk <100 MB": why does a copy take so long?

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, ntfs, veracrypt

I created a "Dynamic" VeraCrypt container of size 10 GB, i.e. it will grow when the usage needs it.

As it's initally empty, in reality it takes less than 100 MB on disk.

**Why does it still take a few minutes to copy with Windows Explorer to an external USB HDD (normal time for 10 GB with my USB2 device), rather than a few seconds, as the file in reality takes less than 100 MB?**

Why does it copy the full 10 GB whereas only < 100 MB are used?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Copying a sparse file may well "copy" the empty space. Seems we have a duplicate question at https://superuser.com/questions/657780/copymove-sparse-files-on-ntfs-with-windows

Comment: The second paragraph of your error message even states as much. Moving the container to another disk "will be extended to the maximum" and even states a method around it.

Comment: @Mokubai Yes indeed (I saw this in the screenshot), but why is that so?

Comment: Because as far as the copying program is concerned you have a 10GB file. That the disk units are not allocated is transparent to applications. As far as programs (explorer included) the file is almost entirely zeroes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file